# passing references of a vector as a target variable of the rpart formulae inside a loop in R

Tags: r, loops, na, missing-data, rpart

sample data:

```
x <- sample(c("aa", "bb", "cc", NA), 5000, replace = TRUE)
y <- sample(c("mm", "nn", "pp", NA), 5000, replace = TRUE)
z <- sample(c("uu", "vv", "ww", NA), 5000, replace = TRUE)
m <- sample(c(1:99, NA), replace = TRUE)
data <- data.frame(x, y, z, m)
```

creating a vector of Target variable for rpart

```
colname <- names(data[ , -m])
```

passing reference by colname index as target variable to rpart for imputing NA values in x, y , z:

```
    for(i in seq_along(colname)) {
  fm <- as.formula(paste0(colname[i], "~ ."))
  mod <- rpart(fm, data = data, method = "class")
  i1 <- is.na(data[[colname[i]]])
  pred <- predict(mod, data[[colname[i]]][i1],   type = "class")

  data[[colname[i]]][i1] <- pred[i1]

}
```

i get the following error:

```
    Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action, xlev = attr(object,  : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'm')
```

Answer (score 1):

We create the formula with `paste` and then do the assignment only for the NA elements

```
library(rpart)
for(i in seq_along(colname)) {
  fm <- as.formula(paste0(colname[i], "~ ."))
  m <- rpart(fm, data = data, method = "class")
  i1 <- is.na(data[[colname[i]]])
  pred <- predict(m, data[c(colname[i], "m")],   type = "class")[i1]

  data[[colname[i]]][i1] <- pred[i1]

}

colSums(is.na(data))
#  x y z 
#  0 0 0
```

#### Update

With the updated dataset, subset the data in the `rpart`

```
colname <- names(data)[1:3]
for(i in seq_along(colname)) {
  fm <- as.formula(paste0(colname[i], "~ ."))
   m <- rpart(fm, data = data[colname], method = "class")
   i1 <- is.na(data[[colname[i]]])
   pred <- predict(m, data[[colname[i]]][i1],   type = "class")

   data[[colname[i]]][i1] <- pred[i1]

 }
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
x <- sample(c("aa", "bb", "cc", NA), 5000, replace = TRUE)
y <- sample(c("mm", "nn", "pp", NA), 5000, replace = TRUE)
z <- sample(c("uu", "vv", "ww", NA), 5000, replace = TRUE)
data <- data.frame(x, y, z)
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun!  I am facing another issue. the actual data i am working with has few additional column of class integer. Lets say an additional column w of class integer. the colname variable contains names  x, y, z which are factor as I only want to fill NA's inx, y and z.

i get the following error

Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action, xlev = attr(object,  : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'w')

Comment: @RaviShankarHela  It is based on the example you showed.  If it is not the example, then you may need to update the example\

Comment: @RaviShankarHela  the `colname` would be `colname <- names(data)[1:3]`

Comment: @RaviShankarHela  Also, in the `rpart` `m <- rpart(fm, data = data[colname], method = "class")`

Comment: i want the models to use full dataset for prediction which includes m.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177059/discussion-between-ravi-shankar-hela-and-akrun).